# Use react component as a child or from within the render function of a React component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

Sometimes we use React components within the render function of react component as in:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div>
      ...
      <MYReactComponent/>
      ...
    </div>
  )
}
```

Sometimes I could use a react component as a child of another as with:

```
<ParentReactComp>
     ...
     <MYReactComponent/>
    ...

</ParentReactComp>
```

What is the advantage of one way over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add a component in reander function directly, you will get that component exactly on that position where you have added that component.

But when you use this,

```
<ParentReactComp>
    ...
     <MYReactComponent/>
    ...

</ParentReactComp>
```

In your `ParentReactComp` component you need to explicitly add your child component using

```
{this.props.children}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ramft1)

Answer (score 2):

Declaring individual component within render let you call simple react component with props.

```
<div>
 ...
 <MYReactComponent/>
 ...
</div>
```

You would want to wrap the component within Parent Component when you want

```
<ParentReactComp>
     ...
     <MYReactComponent/>
    ...

</ParentReactComp>
```

1) Wrapper html

2) Pass some data to `MyReactComponent` for composition pattern or use it as container.

3) You may want to get `MyReactComponent` within `ParentReactComp` using `{this.prop.children}`.

**At last both are just react components, you enclose one component into another depending upon the requirement.**

Hope that helps!!!